# Recursion code not working as expected - Python 3

Tags: python, recursion

I am a beginner to programming and in this case cannot understand why this Python code doesn't work as expected.

I am trying to use recursion by calling a function within a function; calling the function n times, and reducing n by 1 to 0 with each loop at which point it will stop.

Instead my code prints 'freak' once, then I get a 'maximum recursion depth' error message.

```
def print_m():
    print ('freak')

def do_n(arg, n)):
    if n >= 0:
        print (do_n(arg,n))
        n = n - 1
```

Comment: You need to decrement n BEFORE your recursive call.

Answer (score 7):

Recursion is not a loop!

You should be *passing* `n - 1` to the recursive call instead of merely `n`, not subtracting one from `n` *after* this call.

Comment: This solved it, thank you, though I the output is 'None' for all calls other than the initial one, which I don't understand. I'll go back to the text book and play around a bit more!

Comment: @Katy, it _should_ be `None` as you're calling the function `do_n` recursively and printing the returned value. This function _doesn't return anything_, so you're getting a `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Passing `n-1` as parameter to recursive call fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the recursive call in line 6 you should pass print (do_n(arg,n-1)) .